# Why is the length of one of the segments negative in the Menelaus' theorem? Aren't all distances by definition positive?

Tags: geometry, definition, triangles, axioms

> Why is the length of one of the segments negative in the Menelaus' theorem? Aren't all distances by definition positive?

I think we all know the Menelaus' theorem, which claims that the following equality in the triangle given below holds:

> [image]
>
> [image]

And as you can see it's implied that one of the segments is negative. Normally, talking about lengths in general, $PQ=QP$, but this case shows that it's actually $PQ=-QP$, while the definition of distance says that $PQ=QP$. There's something I don't understand here - doesn't it contradict the definitions of geometry? Some explanation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go from $A$ to $F$ you have to come back from $F$ to $B$ so the segments $AF$ and $FB$ have opposite orientations.

This theorem uses signed distances rather than absolute ones, and this is quite common in this kind of exercise. It distinguishes between the point $F$ external to $AB$ and the internal point for which the absolute ratio would be the same (but positive). For this theorem you need the external point, and you need the signed distance to pick it out unambiguously.

Comment: It still seems unusual to me. The sign won't help out, won't change anything in any possible calculations, right? We just want to know the length of segments, I still don't understand what the real use of the sign in practice could ever be. By determining the length of the segment, we would just ignore the sign as the scalar size of the segment is the only thing I think could ever matter.

Comment: @mathh Suppose you want to find a point $F$ with the distance $AF=3BF$ and let's suppose that $AB$ is $12$ units long. Then you have a choice between a point $9$ units from $A$ and a point $16$ units from $A$. Only one of these will do for Menelaus, and the sign distinguishes the two. You may also be familiar with vectors, where the vector in the opposite direction is the negative of the original vector - the direction matters. We are allowed to choose conventions which work.